# Efficient Collatz sequence analysis

Tags: optimization, performance, beginner, haskell, comparative-review

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm wondering why my programs are so slow compared to other languages.

Haskell, 6 seconds (x64, -O2):

```haskell
nextCollatz :: Int -> Int
nextCollatz x = if even x
    then quot x 2
    else 3 * x + 1

collatzLength :: Int -> Int
collatzLength x = if x == 1
    then 0
    else 1 + collatzLength (nextCollatz x)

main = print . show . sum . map collatzLength $ [1..3000000]
```

Julia, 0.8 seconds (excluding the compilation time):

```julia
function main()
    sum = 0
    for i = [1:3000000]
        while i > 1
            i = isodd(i) ? 3 * i + 1 : i >> 1
            sum += 1
        end
    end
    sum
end

println(main())
```

Maybe the comparison isn't fair, but I'd like to know how to improve my Haskell code to bring it on par with other high-level languages such as Julia and JavaScript.

While [memoization and parallelization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/11_to_20#Problem_14) would definitely help, currently I'm concerned with efficient iteration and arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial version - 6.834 seconds.

Version with `quot` and `even` operations replaced with bitwise - 6.651 seconds.

This version - 0.928 seconds:

```
import Data.Bits

tOdd sum 1 = sum
tOdd sum x = tEven (sum + (tEven2 0 x)) (x - 1)

tEven sum x = tOdd (sum + (tOdd2 0 x)) (x - 1)

tEven2 sum x | (x .&. 2) == 0 = tEven2 (sum + 1) (x `shiftR` 1)
tEven2 sum x | otherwise      = tOdd2 (sum + 1) (x `shiftR` 1)

tOdd2 sum 1 = sum
tOdd2 sum x = tEven2 (sum + 1) (3 * x + 1)

main = print . show $ tEven (0 :: Int) (3000000 :: Int)
```

The previous with `-O3 -fllvm -optlo-O3` flags - 0.686 seconds.

The previous with all functions supported with INLINE pragma - 0.604 seconds.

More than 10 times faster than initially :)

Yes, low-level numeric operations and iterations are hard in Haskell, the language doesn't suite well for this.

Comment: OMG, this is impressive. I like your trick with `(x .&. 2)` and splitting the function into even and odd to save some calls and avoid checking parity. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This one is based on my original code with improvements suggested by [leventov](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/50958/19945). Down to 0.7 seconds from the initial 6 seconds thanks to tail recursion and bitwise operations.

```haskell
import Data.Bits

collatzLength :: Int -> Int -> Int
collatzLength sum x
    | x == 1       = sum
    | testBit x 0  = collatzLength (sum + 2) (shiftR (3*x + 1) 1)
    | otherwise    = collatzLength (sum + 1) (shiftR x 1)

main = print $ foldl collatzLength 0 [1..3000000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is non-portable: you might have an `Int` overflow.  An `Int` is only guaranteed to hold up to 2<sup>29</sup> - 1, though the limit could be larger on some systems.

The Collatz sequence for 159487 goes rather high.

```
collatzSeq :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzSeq 1 = [1]
collatzSeq x
  | even x    = x : collatzSeq (x `div` 2)
  | otherwise = x : collatzSeq (3 * x + 1)

*Main> maximum $ collatzSeq 159487
17202377752
*Main> (maximum $ collatzSeq 159487) < 2 ^ 29
False
```

Therefore, you should be using an `Int64` or `Integer` for this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into this issue when I tried using `Word32` and got an overflow on 159487. But `Integer` and `Int64` were 3 times slower than `Int` in my experiments.

Comment: That's weird that `Int64` performs slower than `Int`, if `Int` is already 64-bit arithmetic on your machine.

Comment: Yes, that's so weird. In the [first example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/50973/19945) in my answer if I change `Int` to `Int64` the execution time goes up from 0.6 to 20 seconds! But it the second example I've added `Int64` and the execution time went down from 0.95 to 0.85. I've checked and rechecked several times.